# How to create a Tor Browser shortcut for both runner and menu?

Tags: bash, tor-browser

This is what I did, already:

```bsh
tar -xf tor.tar.xz
mv tor-browser_en-US ~/.local/share/tor
```

After that, I tried creating the shortcut in two different ways. Both of them resulted in the same error:

**first attempt**

```bsh
ln -s $HOME/.local/share/tor/start-tor-browser.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop
```

**second attempt**

```bsh
~/.local/share/tor/start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

Both methods creates an icon, indeed. Although, Tor Browser won't open, at all.

This is the output, when I try to run `start-tor-browser.desktop` directly from the terminal:

```bsh
cd ~/.local/share/applications
./start-tor-browser.desktop
/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: No such file or directory
```

#### Update

This is the content of `start-tor-browser.desktop`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./Browser/execdesktop
#
# This file is a self-modifying .desktop file that can be run from the shell.
# It preserves arguments and environment for the start-tor-browser script.
#
# Run './start-tor-browser.desktop --help' to display the full set of options.
#
# When invoked from the shell, this file must always be in a Tor Browser root
# directory. When run from the file manager or desktop GUI, it is relocatable.
#
# After first invocation, it will update itself with the absolute path to the
# current TBB location, to support relocation of this .desktop file for GUI
# invocation. You can also add Tor Browser to your desktop's application menu
# by running './start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'
#
# If you use --register-app, and then relocate your TBB directory, Tor Browser
# will no longer launch from your desktop's app launcher/dock. However, if you
# re-run --register-app from inside that new directory, the script
# will correct the absolute paths and re-register itself.
#
# This file will also still function if the path changes when TBB is used as a
# portable app, so long as it is run directly from that new directory, either
# via the shell or via the file manager.

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser is +1 for privacy and −1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
Exec=sh -c '"/home/personal/.local/share/tor/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/personal/.local/share/tor/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=/home/personal/.local/share/tor/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

Comment: Check the contents of your desktop file and see if that is correctly pointing to the place where you extracted the browser executable. Also, .desktop files are not executables that you run directly from the terminal, so no use to try that.

Comment: @vanadium I've updated the question body. Turns out, you can execute this `.desktop` file directly in shell, as comments says.

Comment: Did you try putting the .desktop file in .local/share/applications? Then it should appear in your user menu, where you should be able to launch it.

Comment: @vanadium I have tried that, as well. It gives me the same output.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by doing the following:

Go to the to directory where your unpacked browser is, e.g.

```
cd /opt/tor-browser-linux64-10.5.8_de/tor-browser_en
```

Then execute

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

This will copy `start-tor-browser.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`

Now move it manually to `~/Desktop`

It appears on your desktop now. Right click to make it executable. Try if it is basically working by starting the browser. If yes, move it back to `~/.local/share/applications` and press the "option (Windows)" key on your keyboard to launch the app launcher view of Ubuntu. Start typing "tor" => the Tor Browser will appear. Launch it, then it will appear it in the left sidebar. Right click on the icon and add it to the favorites. That's it.